# Что лучше использовать IComparer или IComparable?

Tags: c#

Что лучше использовать для сортировки IComparer или IComparable?Можете сказать что из них лучше использовать и почему? Лично я сам не совсем понял что из них лучше.

Comment: @And, здесь скорее: [When to use IComparable<T> Vs. IComparer<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/538096/2881286)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В `.NET` классов коллекций и массивы поддерживают сортировку,с помощью одного метода, который, как правило, называется `Sort()`.Однако метод `Sort()` по умолчанию работает только для наборов примитивных типов, как `int` или `string`.
Для сортировки наборов сложных объектов применяется интерфейс `IComparable`:

```
public interface IComparable
{
    int CompareTo(object o);
}
```

Метод `CompareTo` на выходе возвращает целое число, которое может иметь одно из трех значений:

- Меньше нуля. Значит, текущий объект должен находиться перед объектом, который 
  передается в качестве параметра
- Равен нулю. Значит, оба объекта равны
- Больше нуля. Значит, текущий объект должен находиться после объекта, передаваемого в качестве параметр

`IComparable` имеет обобщенную версию `IComparable<T>`.
`IComparable<T>`, если определено для `T`, позволяет сравнить текущий экземпляр с другим экземпляром того же типа.

> `IComparable<T>`  сопоставим,а `IComparer<T>` сравнитель.

Кроме интерфейса `IComparable` платформа .NET также предоставляет интерфейс `IComparer`:

```
interface IComparer
{
    int Compare(object o1, object o2);
}
```

Метод `Compare` предназначен для сравнения двух объектов `o1 и o2`. 
Он также возвращает три значения, в зависимости от результата сравнения: 
Если первый объект больше второго,

- то возвращается число больше 0
- если меньше - то число меньше нуля
- если оба объекта равны, возвращается ноль

`IComparer` имеет обобщенную версию `IComparer<T>`.
`IComparer<T>` может быть полезна,когда вам требуется сортировка на основе пользовательского порядка,но не как общее правило.Например,в классе `Person` в какой-то момент вам может потребоваться сортировка людей в зависимости от их возраста. В этом случае вы можете

```
public class Person
{
  public int Age;
}
public class AgeComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
   public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
   {
      return x.Age - y.Age;
   }
}
```

Обычно вам нужно `IComparable<T>`.В идеале вы можете иметь только один `IComparable<T>`, тогда как несколько `IComparer<T>` возможны на основе разных критериев.

Answer (score 6):

Это зависит от того, какой реальный смысл ваших данных.

Если ваша структура данных имеет естественную операцию сравнения, то вы должны реализовать `IComparable<T>` (причин использовать нетипизированный `IComparable` практически нет), при этом сортировка будет работать как надо.

Например, для структуры данных `Rational`, представляющей собой натуральную дробь, операция сравнения очевидна:

```
class Rational : IComparable<Rational>
{
    public int Numerator { get; }
    public int Denominator { get; }

    public int CompareTo(Rational that)
    {
        var result = Math.Sign((this.Numerator * that.Denominator)
                                  .CompareTo(this.Denominator * that.Numerator));
        if (Math.Sign(this.Denominator) != Math.Sign(that.Denominator))
            result = -result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Тогда смысл сортировки понятен: вы сортируете ваши объекты в их естественном порядке.

Если же у ваших объектов нету естественного порядка, то вам нет смысла реализовывать `IComparable<T>`.

Например, если у вас есть объект `Human`, у него нет естественного порядка. Иногда вам может захотеться отсортировать коллекцию людей иногда по росту, иногда по фамилии, иногда по дате рождения. В этом случае для сортировки вы либо указываете, как вычислить «вес» каждого объекта (как в LINQ-шном `OrderBy`), либо указываете, как сравнить два элемента (класс `IComparer<T>` или просто лямбда-функция `Comparison<T>`). Легче всего, наверное, через `OrderBy`:

```
humans.OrderBy(h => h.Surname).ToList()
```

Чуть сложнее через `Comparison<T>`:

```
humans.Sort((p, q) =>
   {
       var n1 = p.Surname;
       var n2 = q.Surname;
       return (n1 > n2) ? 1 :
              (n1 < b2) ? -1 : 0;
   });
```

или просто

```
humans.Sort((p, q) => p.Surname.CompareTo(q.Surname));
```

То же можно сделать и через реализацию интерфейса `IComparer<T>`:

```
class SurnameComparer : IComparer<Human>
{
    public int Compare(Human p, Human q)
    {
        return p.Surname.CompareTo(q.Surname);
    }
}
```

```
var cmp = new SurnameComparer;
humans.Sort(cmp);
```

— но этот путь обычно самый длинный, и нужен не так часто: например, когда вам нужно повторное использование этого «сравнивателя».

Answer (score 3):

Это два разных варианта одного и того же процесса.

1. Интерфейс `IComparable`, позволяет объекту быть "сравниваемым" с другим, что позволяет методом сортировки сортировать коллекции объектов, не вдумываясь что это за объекты. Т.е. объект сам знает, какой у него "статус" к другим объектам. Например есть объект `Email` с полем `email` и `Name` с полем `name`, и есть единый список из `Email и Name`. `Emai`l сравнивает `email.toString()` и `o.toString()` а `Name` соответсвенно с `name`. В итоге, если есть ситуация отсортировать этот общий список, он сортируется правильно, в соответствии с сущностью объектов.
2. Интерфейс `IComparer` позволяет реализовать собственный вариант сортировки, для конкретного случая, учитывая конкретную ситуацию, а не суть классов. Например, можно реализовать на базе этого интерфейса два варианта `ByNameCompare`r и `ByEmailComparer`. И применить их в зависимости от ситуации, к одной коллекции - в одном случай по имени, в другом - по емейлу.