# Как отсортировать список структур по разным полям желательно используя метод Sort

Tags: c#

Есть структура и нужно отсортировать ее по разным полям. Через CompareTo получается сортировка только по одному полю

```
struct Student : IComparable<Student>
{
    public string fio;
    public string group;
    public int[] performance;

    public int CompareTo(Student student)
    {
        return this.fio.CompareTo(student.fio);
    }


}
```

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/812988/213987) и [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/858503/213987)

Comment: _нужно отсортировать ее по разным полям_ -  по каким? _Через CompareTo получается сортировка только по одному полю_ - ничего не мешает проверить несколько полей

Comment: Так допишите сортировку по остальным полям в `CompareTo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Допустим, есть класс `Person`

```
class Person
{
    public string Name{get;}
    public string LastName{get;}

    public Person(string name, string lastName)
    {
        Name = name;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Будем сортировать коллекцию таких классов по имени и фамилии. Напишем компаратор

```
class PersonComparer : IComparer<Person>
{
    public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
    {
        var ret =string.CompareOrdinal(x.LastName, y.LastName);
        if(ret != 0) return ret;
        return string.CompareOrdinal(x.Name, y.Name);
    }
}
```

Как видно, сначала идет сортировка по фамилии. Но если фамилия совпадает, то мы сортируем по имени.

Как использовать:

```
var data = new[] {
    new Person("Vasya", "Pupkin"),
    new Person("Petya", "Pupkin"),
    new Person("Alesha", "Pupkin"),
    new Person("Vasya", "Borisov"),
};

Array.Sort(data, new PersonComparer());

foreach (var p in data)
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.LastName} {p.Name}");
```

Вывод

```
Borisov Vasya
Pupkin Alesha
Pupkin Petya
Pupkin Vasya
```

Если вам нужна фабрика компараторов, то вот пример

```
static class PersonComparer
{
    public static IComparer<Person> Create<T>(Func<Person, T> accessor)where T : IComparable
    {
        return new PersonComparerImpl<T>(accessor);
    }

    class PersonComparerImpl<T> : IComparer<Person> where T : IComparable
    {
        Func<Person, T> _accessor;

        public PersonComparerImpl(Func<Person, T> accessor)
        {
            _accessor = accessor;
        }

        public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
        {
            return Comparer.Default.Compare(_accessor(x),_accessor(y));
        }
    }
}
```

Как использовать

```
var data = new[] {
new Person("Vasya", "Pupkin"),
new Person("Petya", "Pupkin"),
new Person("Alesha", "Pupkin"),
new Person("Vasya", "Borisov"),
};

Array.Sort(data, PersonComparer.Create(p => p.LastName));

foreach (var p in data)
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.LastName} {p.Name}");

Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");

Array.Sort(data, PersonComparer.Create(p => p.Name));

foreach (var p in data)
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.LastName} {p.Name}");
```

Вывод

```
Borisov Vasya
Pupkin Vasya
Pupkin Petya
Pupkin Alesha
--------------------------
Pupkin Alesha
Pupkin Petya
Borisov Vasya
Pupkin Vasya
```

---

Развивая тему, можно накатать фабрику для сортировки по нескольким полям. Пример

```
static class PersonComparer
{
    public static IComparer<Person> Create(params Func<Person, IComparable>[] accessors) 
    {
        return new PersonComparerImpl(accessors);
    }

    class PersonComparerImpl : IComparer<Person> 
    {
        Func<Person, IComparable>[] _accessors;

        public PersonComparerImpl(Func<Person, IComparable>[] accessors)
        {
            _accessors = accessors;
        }

        public int Compare(Person x, Person y)
        {
            foreach (var accessor in _accessors)
            {
                var ret = Comparer.Default.Compare(accessor(x), accessor(y));
                if (ret != 0) return ret;
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Как использовать

```
var data = new[] {
new Person("Vasya", "Pupkin"),
new Person("Petya", "Pupkin"),
new Person("Alesha", "Pupkin"),
new Person("Vasya", "Borisov"),
};

Array.Sort(data, PersonComparer.Create(p => p.LastName));

foreach (var p in data)
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.LastName} {p.Name}");

Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");

Array.Sort(data, PersonComparer.Create(p => p.Name));

foreach (var p in data)
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.LastName} {p.Name}");

Console.WriteLine("--------------------------");

Array.Sort(data, PersonComparer.Create(p => p.LastName, p=>p.Name));

foreach (var p in data)
    Console.WriteLine($"{p.LastName} {p.Name}");
```

Вывод

```
Borisov Vasya
Pupkin Vasya
Pupkin Petya
Pupkin Alesha
--------------------------
Pupkin Alesha
Pupkin Petya
Borisov Vasya
Pupkin Vasya
--------------------------
Borisov Vasya
Pupkin Alesha
Pupkin Petya
Pupkin Vasya
```

Comment: Спасибо, в целом вы помогли, просто я немного некорректно задал вопрос.В моем случае решением будет написать  3 класса компаратора, для каждого поля, либо один и в констукторе передавать ему по какому полю сортировать

Comment: @Sectarian обновил ответ