# Как отсортировать односвязный список сформированный на базе структуры с 4 полями?

Tags: c#, struct

Подскажите какой самый эффективный способ сортировки списка структур? Можете ли вы объясниться как правильно описать функцию сортировки через IComparable? И как он работает "внутри"?

Мы имеем:
структуру с поля:  Index, Date, Time, Title.
на основе этой структуры создан односвязный список: `List<Struct> newList = new List<Struct>(3)`
Нужна возможность сортировки по всем 4 полям. Предположим что мы сортируем по Date->Time->Title.Length->Index.

Comment: Если говорите про код, то код и добавляйте. Также стоит добавлять входные данные и то, что хотите получить. Ну а про сам вопрос: попробуйте LINQ (`var result = newList.OrderBy( x=> new { x.Date, x.Time, x.Time.Length, x.Index } );`).

Comment: Также можете посмотреть например [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/891259/220553) (в комментариях там тоже хорошие ссылки).

Comment: 1) Закинуть структуры в обычный список или массив 2) отсортировать 3) собрать из результата односвязнй список

Comment: Это список из какой-то библиотеки или написан вами? Есть ли в нём метод сортировки? Есть ли в нём метод перестановки двух соседних узлов?

Comment: Список написан мной. Нет, метода сортировки нету, реализовал сортировку по совету EvgeniyZ  через OrderBy. На столько зелен, что не совсем понял что это такое, не могли бы вы скинуть ссылку на информацию о таком методе или же описать более простыми словами, для "зеленых"?

Answer (score 0):

правильно описать функцию сортировки через IComparable?

```
public static class Program
{
  public struct Struct
  {
    public DateTime Date { get; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; }
    public string Title { get; }
    public int Index { get; }

    public Struct(int id, string title, int year, int month, int day, int hour, int 
      minute, int second)
    {
      Index = id;
      Title = title;
      Date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
      Time = new TimeSpan(hour, minute, second);
    }
  }

  private static void Main()
  {
    List<Struct> newList = new List<Struct>
    {
      new Struct(3, "Заголовок", 2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),  
      new Struct(2, "Заголовок", 2020, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), 
      new Struct(1, "Заголовок", 2020, 1, 1, 1, 5, 0), 
    };
    WriteList("До сортировки:", newList);
    newList.Sort(new Comparer());
    WriteList("После сортировки:", newList);
  }

  private static void WriteList(string s, List<Struct> list)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
    foreach (var item in list)
      Console.WriteLine(
        $"Date={item.Date} time={item.Time} title='{item.Title}' 
    index={item.Index}");
    Console.WriteLine();
  }
}

public class Comparer : IComparer<Program.Struct>
{
  public int Compare(Program.Struct x, Program.Struct y)
  {
    int dateComparison = x.Date.CompareTo(y.Date);
    if (dateComparison != 0)
      return dateComparison;
    int timeComparison = x.Time.CompareTo(y.Time);
    if (timeComparison != 0) 
      return timeComparison;
    int titleComparison = string.Compare(x.Title, y.Title, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    if (titleComparison != 0) 
      return titleComparison;
    return x.Index.CompareTo(y.Index);
  }
}
```

Как-то так.